# Is there any halal dating?What type of dating is considered Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

From what I know dating is haram.
But if I want to know whether a lady is suitable for me or not, How can I approach the lady and talk without worrying about other having transparency to our conversation.
Are there any way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Halal dating. Any form of intimate interaction private or public that does not involve a woman's guardian is Haram. "Dating" in Islam is your intention to determine if you and a woman are suitable for marriage.

To determine if a woman is suitable for you, speak to her father, by way of asking her brothers, or your local Imam to introduce you to her father/guardian. After her guardian determines that you are not a mass murdering drug addict and that she actually is interested in you, the process of meeting her publicly with supervision
so that you may discuss what you want from her and what she wants from you can begin.

Allahu A'lam

Comment: Thank you brother for clarification.